# Django form - can I return any variables when raising a ValidationError

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have built a custom form, with several custom fields (containing the primary keys of my models) so I am not using clean_() methods, just clean().

I obtain data out, and if a field doesn't contain certain inputs, I raise a ValidationError. However, I would not like this to fully reset my form inputs... Is there a way to 'save' the state of the form when submitting... or return values even when you are raising a validation error?

form:

```
def clean(self):

    data = self.data
    my_data = data.getlist('my_data')

    ... use my_data to create pandas dataframe ...

    missing = df.loc[(
                      ((df['status'] == 'report') | (df['status'] == 'toconfirm')) &
                       (df['evidence'] == ''))]

    if not missing_evidence.empty:

        error_ids = missing_evidence['obj'].tolist()
        error_variants = [str(o) for o in error_ids]
        error_variants = "; ".join(error_variants)

        raise(forms.ValidationError(('%(value)s incorrect'),
                    params={'value': error_variants},
                ))
        ** here can I return dataframe, and re-set up my form? **
```

Comment: You are not resetting the values, you can still use `form.data['field_name']` to obtain the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can return the same instance of form to template and it will contain all the submitted data

```
form = SomeForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # Do sucess step tasks here
else:
    return render (request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Now you can access the field's value by `form.field.value` in template like

```
<input type='text' name='first_name' value='{{form.first_name.value}}'>
```